# How to loadDesign into unlayer editor from database?

Tags: javascript, laravel, editorjs

I am trying to load my existing HTML markup into the unlayer editor. I am using Raw JavaScript. her is my code. I created a new page that's working fine. The documentation says there has a loadTemplate and loadDesign function to render the HTML markup into the editor. but it's not working.

```
<div id="editor-container" style="height: 79vh;">



<script>
    class EmailEditor {
        constructor(id) {
            unlayer.init({
            id: id,
            displayMode: "web",
            appearance: {
                theme: 'dark',
            }
            });
        }

        loadDesign(design) {
            unlayer.loadDesign(design);
        }

        saveDesign(callback) {
            unlayer.saveDesign(callback);
        }
        exportHtml(callback) {
            unlayer.exportHtml(callback);
        }
    }

        const editor = new EmailEditor('editor-container');

        const saveHTMLBtn = document.getElementById('update_html_btn');

        saveHTMLBtn.addEventListener('click',e => {
        editor.exportHtml(
            d => {
                // Ajax

                var body = d.html;

                $.post('{{ route('api.page.content.create') }}', 
                {_token:'{{ csrf_token() }}', 
                page_id: '{{ $content->id }}', 
                title: '{{ $content->title }}',
                body: body
            },  
                function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                });

              }
            );
        });
      </script>
```

Comment: If you are using this with Laravel, please share your `Blade template` for this page, your `layout` or head (maybe you are missing the script that will load it... Also, do you have any error in the browser JavaScript console ?

Answer (score 0):

There has no unlayer editorjs error in the console. http://prntscr.com/10oqkh4

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title','Page Content Edit')
@section('page-style')
    <script src="http://editor.unlayer.com/embed.js"></script>
@endsection
@section('content')


<button id="update_html_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Update Page</button>
  {{-- <button id="save_json_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Save JSON</button> --}}
  {{-- <button id="load_json_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Load JSON</button> --}}

<div id="editor-container" style="height: 79vh;">

</div>

@endsection


@section('page-script')
    <script>

    class EmailEditor {
        constructor(id) {
            unlayer.init({
            id: id,
            displayMode: "web",
            appearance: {
                theme: 'dark',
            }
            });
        }

        loadDesign(design) {
            unlayer.loadDesign(design);
        }

        saveDesign(callback) {
            unlayer.saveDesign(callback);
        }
        exportHtml(callback) {
            unlayer.exportHtml(callback);
        }
    }

        const editor = new EmailEditor('editor-container');

        const saveHTMLBtn = document.getElementById('update_html_btn');

        saveHTMLBtn.addEventListener('click',e => {
        editor.exportHtml(
            d => {
                // Ajax

                var body = d.html;

                $.post('{{ route('api.page.content.create') }}', 
                {_token:'{{ csrf_token() }}', 
                page_id: '{{ $content->id }}', 
                title: '{{ $content->title }}',
                body: body
            },  
                function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                });

              }
            );
        });

    </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: What if therer's only export html result saved? How do I load it back to unlayer editor?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved saving both the design and the content.

I suggest `design` column to be `JSON` type and `content` column as `longtext` type

The HTML:

```
<form>
    <div id="content"></div><!-- here the plugin is loaded -->
    <input type="hidden" name="design"><!-- leave empty for later -->
    <input type="hidden" name="content"><!-- leave empty for later -->
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Init of the tool:

```
<script>
    unlayer.init({
        id: 'content',
    });
    //I recover the design from the DB and put into a variable
    unlayer.loadDesign({{ design|default|json_encode|raw }});
</script>
```

Content saving:

```
<script>
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        unlayer.exportHtml(function (data) {
            //I export the data and populate the inputs...
            $('form [name="design"]').val(JSON.stringify(data.design));
            $('form [name="content"]').val(data.html);

            $.post(
                'my-url',
                $('form').serialize() //So I can post them to the backend
            ).done(function () {
                //do your things
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i did the same thing and everything went okey! thank you!